# Samsung galaxy S Duos 2 gt-s7582 codename error

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, twrp

Trying to install ressurection remix 7.1 ends in error because my samsung which should be named kyleprods is named kylepro(which is the codename for gt-s7580).

Also, there is no OS installed on it yet, it is erased.

Is there a way to change it? The system folder is empty so no build info.

Trying to install an OS for kylepro(gt-s7580) ends in unable to mount /system error.

To note, I have TWRP recovery.

Edit: It is 7582 because of the sticker under the battery + booting screen.

Answer (score -1):

Go to download mode and flash with stock rom https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=385035244224393610 
hope your problem will be solved.

Comment: Please don't provide random unverified links.  What is the source of this file/link?

Answer (score -2):

Solved by installing another TWRP Recovery, the other one was mislabeled.